# Scrapy Xpath AttributeError : exceptions.AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy, attributeerror

I want to crawl news site and I need collect links.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
import codecs 
import re
from urlparse import urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from hurriyet.items import HurriyetItem

class hurriyet_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hurriyet'
    start_domains = ['hurriyet.com.tr']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),'parse',follow=True),)
    def start_requests(self):
            return [Request(url, meta={'domain': domain}, callback=self.parse) for url, domain in zip(self.start_urls, self.start_domains)]

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
            return self.parse(response)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            if("http://" in link):
                if("hurriyet.com" in link):
                    if(".asp" in link):
                        start_urls.append(link)
                    else:
                        print link
                        return self.parse(link)
                start_urls.append(link)
            else:
                print link
                return self.parse(link)

    def news_downloads(self, response):
        image = HurriyetItem()
        image['source'] = link
        image['title'] = response.xpath("//h1[@class = 'title selectionShareable'] | //h1[@itemprop = 'name']/text()").extract()
        image['body'] = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'detailSpot']").extract()
        image['body2'] = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'ctx_content'] ").extract()
        return image
```

But doesn't work and say:

> links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
>           exceptions.AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath'

I tried deleting ".extract()" but it is not working.

Comment: please share the complete spider code

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here either use `crawl-spider` or to use a `base-spider`, seems like you are mixing everything here.

solution is,

Either you can use `BaseSpider`

```
from scrpy import Spider
class hurriyet_spider(Spider): 
    name = 'hurriyet' 
    allowed_domains = ['hurriyet.com.tr'] 
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            # your code here
```

or a `Crawl-Spider`

```
class hurriyet_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hurriyet' 
    allowed_domains = ['hurriyet.com.tr'] 
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item',follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            # your code here
```

**EDIT**

`return self.parse(link)` will be the possible error returning code, since you are giving a `unicode` object to `parse()` as parameter and where in the body you are accessing `xpath()` for that `unicode` object. Since there is no function named `xpath()` for a `unicode-object` you are getting this error. You have to give a `response object`/`scrapy selector-object` instead of `unicode` to use the `xpath()` function.

Comment: I try both of them BaseSpider and CrawlSpider not work same error again

Comment: try removing the following lines I have mentioned in the answer , that should work

Comment: did you remove both `return self.parse(link)` statements ? and still getting the same error ? By the way why are you appending the `link` in `start-urls`? you haven't added a local list named `start-urls`, if you are accessing global list variable `start-urls` better make it `self.start-urls`